# How to get Skype Group Chat ID

Tags: python-3.x

How to find the the SkypeGroupChat ID from the a Skype account. I would like to send message to a Skype group using Skype API (SkPy with python)

Answer (score 8):

I found out another way to view the chat id:

- Login your [Web Skype](https://web.skype.com) use Chrome,
- press F12 to open developer tool,
- switch to "Network" tab, then send some message in the chat group you need to know the id,
- lookup the network records, you will find some requests to send message like this:

```
Request URL: https://client-s.gateway.messenger.live.com/v1/users/ME/conversations/19%3Axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%40thread.skype/messages?x-ecs-etag=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx....
```

after "conversations" in the path,  "19:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...@thread.skype" is chat group id as you want. (%3A is ":", %40 is "@")

Comment: The finished id should look something like: 19:91ba33d9b127fee124bd68f2a12495a0@thread.skype

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem.

Here is my code to find GroupID:

```
from skpy import Skype, SkypeChats

sk = Skype("userID", "password")
skc = SkypeChats(sk)
skc.recent()
```

then get information of recent conversations on terminal like

```
{'19:xxxxx...@thread.skype': SkypeGroupChat(id='19:xxxxx...@thread.skype', ....
```

On skpy document, declaring that *Group conversation identifiers looks like 19:<random>@thread.skype.*

Comment: Best way to do integration and know group ID

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
from skpy import Skype

sk = Skype("userID", "password")
chats = sk.chats

for i in chats:
    print(i)
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Why is this preferable over the existing answers?