# How to send an automated message to a skype group chat using python

Tags: python-3.x, skype

Even though i am able to send messages to an individual skype contact using skpy module. i am unable to send to a group chat.

Below is the simple code i've used to send:

```
from skpy import Skype
sk = Skype("myskypeID", "pwd") # connect to Skype
content="the message i wanna send"
ch = sk.contacts["SkypeID_in_contacts"].chat 
ch.sendMsg(content)
```

I cannot find any skype group ID for my group chats. Is there anyway of finding a skype group ID or some other method to append with python code i have used. 
Please help

Answer (score 2):

All Group Chart in Skype have an ID like

```
19:<random>@thread.skype
```

Here you can find a simple script to found all your groups IDs
[How to get Skype Group Chat ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45862364/how-to-get-skype-group-chat-id)

End then you can found your chat with that id

```
ch = sk.chats["19:0b85483d2d634415993bb9daf58e7891@thread.skype"]
ch.sendMsg(msg)
```

Comment: Each skype name has a unique skypeID. But there is are no IDs for the group chat in my skype contact list. The code only works for skypeIDs not group skype names my friend. 
Could you plz help.
 This could really help us automate alot of routine tasks we do during the day.

Comment: Sorry. My previous answer was not correct. But i have found a correct one and test it.

Comment: I get no results for the given script
`from skpy import Skype, SkypeChats

sk = Skype("userid", "pwd")
skc = SkypeChats(sk)
skc.recent()`

Comment: Thanks!!! this worked well. but recently im gettin following error from nowhere. Do you mind looking onto this?

`File "C:\Python3\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\skpy\conn.py", line 288, in readToken
    raise SkypeAuthException("No token file specified")`

Comment: You have to connect to skype via browser and check that skype is work. SKPY library based on Skype for Web. I also had this error until connect to Skype via browser. The web skype try to show capctha for your python programme. And you have to connect manually for the first time.

Comment: Also you can check this similar thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344035/sending-a-message-in-skype-using-skpy-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: how to send a file in multiple groups ?

Comment: do you know if it is possible two send a message to multiple groups at the same time ?!